# How to convert a linq array to string array for json

Tags: vb.net, json, linq

i have this function in VB.NET

```
Dim dt = (From d In db.d ...).ToArray()

Return New With {
    .label = "label",
    .data = dt.ToArray()
}
```

that returns the following data in JSON format

```
{
    "label":"label",
    "data":[
        {"date":1366657400000,"value":12051},
        {"date":1366657397000,"value":12102},
        {"date":1366646820000,"value":12099}
    ]
}
```

How can I go about returning the data in the following format

```
{
    "label":"label",
    "data":[
        [1366657400000,12051],
        [1366657397000,12102],
        [1366646820000,12099]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? The original JSON looks better to me.

Comment: @svick I agree, but I need to do so in order for Flot plugin to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with VB, but it should look something like this:

```
Return New With { _
    .label = "label", _
    .data = data.[Select](Function(d) New Long() { d.date, d.value} ).ToArray() _
}
```

The idea is that you want to create a new array for each item in your original collection. The first item in the new array is the `date` property, and the second item is the `value` property.

This is what it would look like in C#:

```
return Json(new {
    label = "label",
    data = data.Select(d => new[] { d.date, d.value }).ToArray()
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't compile. I tried

    Return New() With {
        .label = "label",
        .data = data.ToArray()
    }
but it gives me a syntax error 'Type expected'

Comment: I know how to write it in c#, I found a similar answer here but I don't know how to convert d => new[] to VB. The syntax New() With doesn't compile.

Comment: Write `new string()` in place of `new[]`, to start with - assuming its going to be a string array.

Comment: @Elio - Sorry... as I said, I don't know VB very well. But the method is correct: create a new array from each item in the original data collection. That way, an array of arrays is serialized, and you should get your desired output.

Comment: @Elio - I fixed the VB example. It now compiles and works for me.

Comment: Doesn't New With create an anonymous type?  Does VB allow you to return an anonymous type from a function??

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I suspect he's serializing the anonymous type instance with the Json method, but that call wasn't in his original example so I left it out of mine.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I do serialize the anonymous type by overriding the return of the function. I am using this very useful piece of code [http://www.codeproject.com/articles/353260/asp-net-advanced-generic-handler-ashx](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/353260/asp-net-advanced-generic-handler-ashx) Makes it very easy to work with ajax!